Fraction and inverted fraction: a name for it?
(I hope this question is in scope here. I use this function in a DSP related module.)
Is there a name for a calculation that on a call with unsigned integer parameter values val1 and val2 returns:
(A) unsigned integer fraction of val1/val2 (tagged with an enum value: gt1) if val1 > val2
(B) unsigned integer fraction of val2/val1 (taggen with an enum value: lt1) if val2 > val1
(C) 1 if val1 == val2
One could also consider just returning the negative value on case B, and drop the tags.
One could also consider signed integer input params here, but that's kind of not in scope for this question.
I use such a function, but I struggle in finding a good name for it.
div_or_invert_div isn't really a proper name, I'd say.

None, that I know of.  I'll suggest: ratio_ge1

Is there some content regarding Signal Processing (either analog or digital) in this question?

$$ e^{\operatorname{sgn}(val_1-val_2)} $$

The ratios are the sum of the power bins of some points I "listen for" divided-with-this-formula with the sum of the power of all the other bins. Positive ratio if the energy I want is higher then the rest, negative if the power of the rest is more than what I listen for. So little ambient noise vs. much of it. These values are the sum of of the energies re * re + im * im after a 256 FFT, before the square root magnitude. I did hope this qualified as Signal Processing percentage high enough to trigger some interest here.

Churning about this I have started to define the term "pivot div" for this.
I have also included (which must be tested before (A))
(D) 0 if val1 is zero and val2 not, the opposite, or both zero

As said in the previous comment, have started to define the term "pivot div" for this formula. I guess this would answer my own question.

If positive and negative results are what you are looking for, why not just take the log of the ratio. Your case (C) would give 0 not 1 of course. If your taking the mean of the sums of bins, then this would just be plain old SNR. Apologies if I missed the reason it needs to be more complicated than this.

Absolutely a good idea! And my val1/val2 and val2/val1 do have qualities I think where something log might do it. Like val1 values are most often much above val2 values but when val2s are largest they don't seem to be that much above the val1s. But I'll fight this along the axis of normalising as long as I can and make sure that val1 and val2 represent the same thing. I also listen for max 8 recorded sounds which would each have their unique patterns, which only makes things more difficult. But the SW is installed and certainly works, but I haven't finished this feature yet.

I now have short movie showing it in function. The old micromaperemeter is PWM pulsed at 250 Hz (instead of analogue) and shows val1>=val2 as "green" values above the center, and val1<val2 as red values below the center. "Green" are wanted relative energies, "red" values are unwanted energies, summed at 32 spectra over 1024 ms. The movie is at link
